# Could yarn support running in "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022"?

Tags: node.js, cmd, ms-office, visual-studio-2022, yarn-v3

In "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022" (Administrator):

```
npm install yarn -g
```

And then, run

```
yarn --version
```

It returns 3.2.1. But I found windows changed from "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022" to "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe".

**Environment:**

nodejs : v18.17.0

I hope it still keep the window:"x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022", Could you help with me for this issue.

```
echo %PATH%
```

It contains the path: C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: What happens if you use `call npm install yarn -g`?